# AlertDialog quando ha uma excepção

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber como faço com que um AlertDialog seja mostrado ao user quando ha uma excepção , no android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente crie um `try catch` e insira seu código dentro do `try`. Caso der alguma exceção dentro do `try`, cairá no `catch` e exibirá um `AlertDialog`. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
try {

    // Aqui você coloca o código que talvez venha dar uma exceção

} catch (Exception e){

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Exception");
    alertDialog.setMessage(e.toString());
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```